# How to change the preview section's background based on the theme?

Tags: storybook

I'm using Tailwind CSS for styling my app. Using the [storybook-addon-themes](https://storybook.js.org/addons/storybook-addon-themes), I add dark/light class to the HTML element of the preview's iframe, so my components have different styles based on the theme. How should I change the preview section's background based on the theme? I can manually (using the button in the toolbar) change the background with the background add-on, but I want to keep it in sync with the theme.

One possible solution that came to my mind is to add Tailwind CSS classes (something like `bg-light dark:bg-dark`) to the iframe so I can control the background with the CSS classes. Besides the fact that I don't know how to do that, I don't like it. Is there a better solution?

My preivew.js file:

```
export const parameters = {
  ...
  themes: {
    target: "html",
    default: "Dark",
    list: [
      {
        name: "Dark",
        class: ["dark"],
        color: "#000",
      },
      { name: "Light", class: ["light"], color: "#fff" },
    ],
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [withThemeByClassName](https://storybook.js.org/blog/styling-addon-configure-styles-and-themes-in-storybook#not-using-react-or-jsx-no-problem).

The current theme will be added as a class to the top-level `<html>` tag.

You need to add it to the `decorators` object in your .storybook/preview.js file, like so:

```
const preview: Preview = {
  decorators: [
    ...
    withThemeByClassName({
      themes: { dark: "dark", light: "light" },
      defaultTheme: "dark",
    }),
  ],
  ...
```